# Cache Control In Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, cache-control

I have a Drupal site where if i view the Request Header Cache Control, it is set to the following:

no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0

However, i'm not seeing anywhere in the code where those headers are set.

I'm looking to add no-store to the cache control, and i was able to achieve that by doing the following:

```
drupal_add_http_header('cache-control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
```

to the preprocess_html function of the theme.  However, i want to ensure i'm doing it the right away and thats i'm not overwriting Drupal default or if there is a better way to set the header.

I did not have anything in the .htaccess in regard to cache control.

Thanks.

Comment: I found that the default headers are set in the following location: bootstrap.inc in the following function:  durpal_page_header.  The question now if drupal_add_http_header is the correct way of modifying the header to include the no-store header.

Comment: After more research i found that using drupal_add_http_header is the correct way to override drupal headers.  In theory drupal should update their default to include no-store.